# How to implement mutli party P2P Video conference using PeerJS?

Tags: webrtc, p2p, peerjs

I am planning to create a multiparty P2P call , where all participants send their media to all the rest of the participants.

How to do this ?

PeerJS supports only 1 : M

That is

If A starts a meeting

B calling A , and both sharing their streams

Now C calling A and both sharing their streams

Now A streaming to B and C

Now the problem is

B and C cannot communicate with each other

I need this only . I need all peers have to stream to all peer in multi direction manner M:N

Please guide me

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? If so then any help would be greatly appreciated. :)